# Best way to save only time in rails with postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm having a small mindblow, what's the best way to store only time in rails?

Likely I'm having 3 options in my head

1. Store it as DateTime but ignore the date part
2. Store it as an integer in seconds/minutes
3. Store it as a decimal

What you could suggest to me and why? :)

Postgres 13

Rails 6.0.3

Ruby 2.7.2

Comment: You could use a [`time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:~:text=time%20of%20day%20%28no%20date%29) value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time is a built-in Rails column type](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column) which works with [Time objects](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html). It will use the [Postgres time (without time zone) type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:%7E:text=time%20of%20day%20%28no%20date%29).

You can manually use `time with time zone` which will also map to Time, but it will retain the time zone.

`add_column(:yourtable, :time_at, 'time with time zone')`

See [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) for more about how to work with time in Rails.

Comment: Ruby time != Postgres time. Postgres time is *only* time (hh:mm:ss) while Rails time is DateTime. AFAIK there is no way to represent a PG time value in ActiveRecord as Ruby does not have a time only object. Returning a Rails AR time column will return a Time object which includes date and also is unable to accurately represent 24:00:00 from Postgres time type.

Comment: @Espen You ignore the date part. Remember, the point is to store a time, not to be 100% compatible with the Postgres time type.

Comment: That is not at all compatible because Postgres has 24:00. No such thing exists in Ruby. It will be '02 jan 00:00' instead of just 24:00. Rails will actually not interpret 24:00 accurately at all. So the point of storing a time is not accomplished.

Comment: @Espen Again, we're not looking to round trip Postgres time, we're looking to round trip Rails time. We only need Rails time to be a *subset* of Postgres time. 24:00 isn't how Rails represents the end of day, [Rails uses 23:59:59.999999](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-end_of_day). Even ISO 8601 considered dropping 24:00. One can either add constraint to prevent 24:00 from being somehow stored (you could even make a custom type), or interpret 24:00 as 23:59:59.999999 (which Rails might do, I haven't checked).